# Insert, Update, Delete query in one Stored Procedure with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I created multiple queries in one `Stored Procedure`. Check below example:
**i.e.**

```
IF(@Type='add')
BEGIN
   Insert query
END

IF(@Type='get')
BEGIN
   Select query
END
```

I am using `Entity Framework` in my `MVC` project. So, I am getting error: `does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name`.
Is it necessary to create different `Stored Procedures` for each query? How do I achieve whatever I am trying to do?

Comment: It is about choice of how you want to write it.

Comment: Can you show how you are setting the `query` value?

Comment: @S.Dav I am adding Entity Framework model (Ado.NET entity data model and EF Designer from Database).

Comment: `So, I am getting error: does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.` At compile time? When defining the model? At runtime? Something else? Please also include the **full** stored proc source code.

Comment: Personally I'd separate them

Comment: @juharr Is it recommended?

Comment: Agree with @juharr, separate them, and name them that way try to keep one purpose per procedure make life simpler in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you got has nothing to do with the queries included in the procedure, you can include both the insert and select queries in the procedure with no problem.

**The select query must be after the insert, so that the query results returned from the stored procedure and therefore entity framework can map the properties correctly to the model.**

Another issue, I think, is that the select query, doesn't return the full entity model, I think you only returned specific columns not all the columns.

**I recommend that you split them into two different procedures, so that the select query can be mapped to a model. and the insert query works fine without select.**

Comment: In my above stored procedure, If I add select query after insert statement then it works fine.
`IF(@Type='add')
BEGIN
   Insert query
   Select query where id=last id
END`

Comment: Yes It has to be after the insert so that it returns to the results back from the stored procedure.

Comment: @JeetenParmar - See me update

Comment: What If I don't want to return anything after insert statement ?

Comment: @JeetenParmar Then you have to handle this from the entity framework mapping, so that don't map it to the model in this case

Comment: @JeetenParmar Or make them two different procedures.